# Isolate code from other scripts (namespace)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing it like this:

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){

  var MyNamespace= MyNamespace || {};

  $.MyNamespace.someMethod = function(){
    // code
  };

  $.MyNamespace.someOtherMethod = function(){
    // code
  };

  $.MyNamespace.someProperty = {};

  // etc.


}(jQuery));
```

is it ok?

Comment: window, document are undefined inside function body.

Comment: I think this belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified code : 
there are two problem.

MyNamespace is property of $.
and window and document are not available inside function body.

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){

  $.MyNamespace= $.MyNamespace || {};

  $.MyNamespace.someMethod = function(){
    // code
  };

  $.MyNamespace.someOtherMethod = function(){
    // code
  };

  $.MyNamespace.someProperty = {};

  // etc.


}(jQuery, window, window.document));
```

Answer (score 3):

In your variable initialization you are setting it to a global `MyNamespace` if that exists, this is not scoped/isolated.

You are then referencing `$.MyNamespace` instead of `MyNamespace` which refer to two very different things. `$` is the parameter that refers to `jQuery` and as such is globally accessible and not isolated from other code.

Use `$.MyNamespace` if you want it accessible to other code and `MyNamespace` if you want to scope the access to just this code.